# Inject the same service instance in many ViewModels

Tags: .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a ViewManager class that manages Views instances.
It is used by the ShellViewModel and by many other ViewModels, and it has to injected through the constructor.
The ShellViewModel has the ViewManager injected.
If I create a new ViewModel using a factory, who should provide the factory with the ViewManager in order to inject it into the new VM?

1. the container? (this means the container injects the ViewManager into the factory, and the factory injects it into the new VM)
2. the ShellViewModel? (this means the ShellVM does something like factory.Create(this.ViewManager)

what's the best way? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way [if you're using MVVM is to use an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). To answer your question, you would want the view manager to be injected via the factory constructor, rather than the factory method, so option 1.

Really though you don't want to be managing view instances yourself - rather use a framework which has already done all of the work for you, rather than reinventing an inferior wheel.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so you suggest me to add a parameter to the factory's constructor and inject there the ViewManager?
Thank you!

Comment: yes that's right, and register it as a singleton in your container if it is the same insance for every factory. Really though think about a framework, you seem to be solving a problem people have already solved extremely well.

Comment: yeah it's just that as a student i really like to understand every aspect and know every mechanism that make it work, so i started building my own simple container and viewmanager, but now things are getting a bit hard to get together so I'm thinking about it :D
thank you!!